# Drawing Program Bug

Tags: java, path, drawing, mouseevent

im programing a small drawing program. 
But i have a bug with painting. left, right, does work correct, but top, bottom creates curious images. why? ANyone a idea? Im programming in java.
The Bug: (left normal, right bug) And no it ISNT because mouseevent isnt getting all points. Im drawing all circles between to points i actually get.  see the code.

[image: left:normal|right:bug]

The code for painting:

```
double m = 0;
int width = draggedX - mouseX;
int height = draggedY - mouseY;
if(draggedX - mouseX != 0){
    m = (double) (draggedY - mouseY) / (double) (draggedX - mouseX);
}
if(width > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        double x = mouseX + i;
        double y = mouseY + (m * i);
        g.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, 5, 5);
    }
}
else if(width < 0){
    for(int i = -width; i > 0; i--) {
        double x = mouseX - i;
        double y = mouseY - (m * i);
        g.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, 5, 5);
    }
}
else{
    if(height > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
            g.fillOval(mouseX, (int) i + mouseY, 5, 5);
        }
    }
    else if(height < 0){
        for(int i = -height; i > 0; i--){
            g.fillOval(mouseX, (int) i - mouseY, 5, 5);
        }
    }
    else{
        g.fillOval(mouseX, mouseY, 5, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mouse events are tricky, they don't always follow a linear progression. Instead of using oval, I would simple paint lines between each distinct event point. If you need to make the lines thicker, the take a look at Stroke (or BasicStroke in particular)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: that should be an answer as it's certainly much better than the answer provided by Joni.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Was looking for an example, I know I've done this thing a few times before

Comment: hmm but the endings have to be "round", and i also want to draw single circles, so that isnt the point

Answer (score 1):

Mouse events are tricky, they don't always follow a linear progression. Instead of using oval, I would simple paint lines between each distinct event point. If you need to make the lines thicker, the take a look at Stroke (or BasicStroke in particular)

For example [Resize the panel without revalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528061/resize-the-panel-without-revalidation/18528140#18528140)

I also have a very bad feeling your a painting directly to the graphics context by using `getGraphics` instead of using `paintComponent`

Comment: im drawing with getGraphics only on the bufferedimage, and this is painted in paintComponenet.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you draw a nearly vertical line with width = 10 and height = 200. With the given loop you will draw exactly 10 points, which is not enough to cover the entire line.

To fix this you need to check if height > width and in that case plot the points "vertically," iterating along the y-axis.

```
// when height > width
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    double x = mouseX + i/m;
    double y = mouseY + i;
    g.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, 5, 5);
}
```

As you can see the algorithm to plot a single line becomes quite complex. That's why [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) is such a big deal.